# Customize Sublime Text 2 with image background

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to customize my Sublime Text with an image in the background (its dark enough for the text to show clearly). I have seen images added as background for the vim text editor and I can change the color scheme in sublime, but I'm not sure how to make the background an uploaded image.

I'm using Linux Ubuntu os, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible in Sublime Text 2.
However, there's already an [open feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/126401-background-image-in-main-window-where-the-code-is-shown/) for it on their UserEcho forum, you can upvote it there.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit dissapointing. I upvoted the feature request.